# Solve nonlinear equation

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function, exponentiation, nonlinear-system

How to solve nonlinear equation: 
$$x+2.1*\frac{100}{1+e^{(10-q(x))/3}}-2=0,\\
here \quad q(x)=\frac{100}{1+e^{(10-x)/3}}$$
Are here any numerical method suitable to solve or any package? I tried Newton method, but didn't get a right answer.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindRoot%5B-2+%2B+210.%60%2F%281+%2B+E%5E%281%2F3+%2810+-+100%2F%281+%2B+E%5E%28%2810+-+x%29%2F3%29%29%29%29%29+%2B++++x%2C+%7Bx%2C+-5%7D%5D).

Comment: Could you tell what was your $x_0$ for Newton method ? It will be intersting to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really do not see what kind of problems you could have faced with Newton method.

Using the values of $x_0$ you used, below are given the iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -2.3881246 \\
 2 & -4.9553903 \\
 3 & -6.1937576 \\
 4 & -6.3118065 \\
 5 & -6.3125527
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & +1.0000000 \\
 1 & -1.1036705 \\
 2 & -3.7121240 \\
 3 & -5.7946726 \\
 4 & -6.2973982 \\
 5 & -6.3125408 \\
 6 & -6.3125527
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: That's strange, because when I was plotting graphics neither of these x_n you got isn't figuring :) Then maybe this way isn't suitable for my problem, but with another similiar task it was working well.

Comment: @AdolfMiszka. These are the **iterates**